# BeanバリデータとJSF標準バリデータの併用

Tags: java-ee, jsf

JSF2.2にて一つの画面に対し、BeanバリデータとJSF標準バリデータ両方使用して入力チェックを実装することを検討していますが、何か弊害はあるでしょうか？
入力チェックがかかるタイミングが異なると思うのでそのことなどが起因で何か弊害がないかと心配しています。
推奨されない理由などありましたらご教授お願いします。